# Return None for KeyError in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, return-value

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVcIT.png)

I need to return "None" for this but I know this is most simple with "get.dict" which wasn't working so I tried this approach. It works to return the correct values but will not return "none" for KeyError

Comment: Please post code here directly, not a screenshot.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) … [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) …[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

You have the order switched.  It should be:

```
stocks_dic.get(stock_price)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `dict.get`  and setting the default to `None`

```py
stocks_dic.get(stock_price, None)
```

This will return `None` if the stock_price isn't in the dictionary instead of `KeyError`

For more information check out `dict.get` in the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)